# Return user_id as response of post api

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I want to return `user_id` for each object created using post api.

I want output in form of

```
[
{"info": {
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "message": "User Details Successfully Uploaded"
        },
        "user_id": 10001
    }
]
```

Here is my Code

**Serializer.py**

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """docstring for UserDetailsSerializer"""
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
        fields = ['user_id', 'user_email', 'user_full_name', 'user_token', 'patient_id', 'user_preferences']
        read_only_fields = ['user_id']
```

**Views.py**

```
class UserDetailsViewSet(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        queryset= UserDetails.objects.all()
        serializer_class=UserDetailsSerializer(queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer_class_post=UserDetailsSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer_class_post.is_valid():
            try:
                serializer_class_post.save()
                return Response([{"info": {
                    "status": "SUCCESS",
                    "message": "User Details Successfully Uploaded"
                },
                    "user_id": serializer_class_post.data
                }], status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except IntegrityError as e:
                return Response([{"info": {
                    "status": "Error",
                    "message": "Error Uploading User Details"
                }
                }], status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(serializer_class_post.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`
```

**models.py**

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key= True)
    user_email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    user_full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_token = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    patient_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
    user_preferences = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'walnut_users'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your post to the following:

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer_class_post=UserDetailsSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer_class_post.is_valid():
        try:
            obj = serializer_class_post.save()
            return Response([{"info": {
                "status": "SUCCESS",
                "message": "User Details Successfully Uploaded"
            },
                "user_id": obj.pk
            }], status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except IntegrityError as e:
            return Response([{"info": {
                "status": "Error",
                "message": "Error Uploading User Details"
            }
            }], status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response(serializer_class_post.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`
```

`serializer.save()` returns the newly created object; just use that and get the pk in your response.

Also, API best practice is to return the full object representation; not the ID alone. Ideally I would do what you have done: `{"data": serializer_post_data.data}` -> this will return the full nested representation. You should still be able to access the `user_id` as `data.user_id`. However, if you are sure about your usecase, the code above will work.

Since `user_id` is an IntegerField and the primary key, then Django expects you to supply the value for the field. Where are you assigning value to user_id - does your API also post the value for user_id. If you want to auto-assign values, change it to `user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`

Comment: [
    {
        "info": {
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "message": "User Details Successfully Uploaded"
        },
        "user_id": null
    }
] It returns null

Comment: user_id is a autoincrement field api is supposed to return user_id to user

Comment: Can you add your model definition?

Comment: class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key= True)
    user_email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    user_full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_token = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    patient_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
    user_preferences = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'walnut_users'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_id

Comment: Where are you assigning value to `user_id` - does your API also post the value for `user_id`. If you want to auto-assign values, change it to `user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`. If it is an `IntegerField` and the primary key, then Django expects you to supply the value for the field

Comment: Alright; updating the same in the response; do accept if it resolved your problem